# Comment package does not work in beamer

Tags: beamer, comments

I want to use the `comment` package in my presentation. I read that it does not always work in some very complicated contexts, but here it fails even in a very simple example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
random text

\begin{comment}
hidden text
\end{comment}

\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

I can't find a solution for this problem in this site. Is there an incompatibility or am I missing something?

Comment: That was it. Anyway, where is it documented? I searched both the docs and found nothing...

Comment: @dcmst you should convert your comment to an answer then

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `comment` environment works by interpreting the content of the environment as verbatim text which is then discarded.

For this reason in `beamer` it needs to be loaded inside a `fragile` frame, like other verbatim text:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]     % fragile option
random text

\begin{comment}
hidden text
\end{comment}

\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

This is not documented directly but is implied by the inner workings of the `comment` package, explained in the documentation.

Comment: However, it seems not to work with `\excludecomment{proof}` even if fragile option is presented