# Out-of-slide comment environment in Beamer

Tags: beamer, comments

I've just read

[Comment package does not work in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152381/comment-package-does-not-work-in-beamer)

explaining how, for `\begin{comment} etc. \end{comment}` to work, it needs to go inside a 'Fragile' frame. But what if I want an out-of-frame comment? Is there some workaround for the comment package, or another package with the same effect which is more, shall we say, forgiving regarding where it's used?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "out-of-frame comment"?

Comment: @samcarter: I mean having that comment environment outside of any frame, immediately within the document environment.

Answer (score 4):

```
This is Text
\iffalse
This is Text, too, but not printed
\fi
Another text
```

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something or can you simply do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
random text
\end{frame} 

\begin{comment}
hidden text
\end{comment}

\end{document}
```

(Works without errors with pdflatex of TeXlive 2015, 2016 and 2017, I have not tested other engines.)

---

Alternatively you could use the `ignorenonframetext` option of beamer:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
random text
\end{frame} 

hidden text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, you are missing something, this gets me an error message.

Comment: @einpoklum Works for me with Texlive2015 and 2016 without errors. What does your error message say?